# Sequelize Scope equivalent

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'd like to get rid of rows where date is later than today - 7 and status is like 'Canceled'.

How can I create Sequelize scope equivalent for that raw query:

```sql
SELECT `st_shipment_header`.`id`, 
 FROM `st_shipment_header` AS `st_shipment_header` 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `st_shipment_event` AS `st_shipment_events` ON `st_shipment_header`.`id` = `st_shipment_events`.`stShipmentHeaderId`
 WHERE (`st_shipment_header`.`id` 
 NOT IN 
 ( SELECT `st_shipment_header`.`id` FROM `st_shipment_header` AS `st_shipment_header` 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN `st_shipment_event` AS `st_shipment_events` ON `st_shipment_header`.`id` = `st_shipment_events`.`stShipmentHeaderId` 
 WHERE (`st_shipment_events`.`date` < NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY ) AND (`st_shipment_header`.`shipmentStatus` LIKE 'Canceled%'))));
```

I have tried this one as a Sequelize scope:

```
StShipmentHeader.addScope('test', {
  include: [
    { model: models.st_shipment_event }
  ],
  where: {
    [Op.notIn]: {
      [Op.and]: {
        'models.st_shipment_event.date': {
          [Op.lt]: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 7)
        },
        shipmentStatus: {
          [Op.like]: '%Canceled%'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

but it looks like `[Op.notIn]` doesn't work...

Comment: Is it because `scope` was not registered or just because query didn't work as expected? It would be much better to add generated SQL as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do finally resolved it by creating different SQL query without `NOT IN`.

```sql
    SELECT 
        `st_shipment_header`.`id`
    FROM
        `st_shipment_header`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
        `st_shipment_event` AS `st_shipment_events` ON `st_shipment_header`.`id` = `st_shipment_events`.`stShipmentHeaderId`
    WHERE
        ((`st_shipment_header`.`shipmentStatus` LIKE 'Canceled%'
            AND `st_shipment_events`.`date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
            OR `st_shipment_header`.`shipmentStatus` NOT LIKE 'Canceled%');
```

```
    StShipmentHeader.addScope('test', {
      include: [
        models.st_shipment_event,
      ],
      where: {
        [Op.and]: {
          [Op.or]: {
            shipmentStatus: {
              [Op.notLike]: 'Canceled%'
            },
            [Op.and]: {
              shipmentStatus: {
                [Op.like]: 'Canceled%'
              },
              'models.st_shipment_event': sequelize.where(
                sequelize.col('st_shipment_events.date'),
                {
                  [Op.gt]: sequelize.literal('NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY')
                }
              )
            }
          },
        }
      }
    })
```

Main changes:

- use `sequelize.col` to identify column,
- use `sequelize.literal('NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY')`,
- use different SQL query